# Как поставить событие на video, когда видео находится в iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, видео, события

Я понял, что `iframe` "изолирован от `document`". Допустим на Youtube есть все возможные API. Вот интересное API https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference. Но что делать если ресурс который предоставляет видео контент не имеет API. Пробовал ставить события на `document`. Если видео не в `iframe` то все работает, а иначе событий нет.

Comment: а событие-то какое?

Comment: хоть play | pause | любое событие которые имеет `<video>`

Comment: [Same-origin security policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098153/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy а Workaround еще работает? Пока что читаю документацию к [`otherWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin, [transfer]);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: @АлексТвояТруба, это _двухсторонний_ Workaround, если встроенный сайт не будет обрабатывать посланных сообщения - то результата не будет. По этому же принципу, кстати, работает и api От youtube, они так же шлют сообщения своему фрейму и обратно

Comment: Немного недоумеваю, а зачем используют `<iframe>` для видео контента если можно просто назначать атрибут  `src` в `<video>`. Тэг давно поддерживает объект [`blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Blob). А может расширения браузера имеют доступ к `<iframe>`.

Comment: _Немного недоумеваю, а зачем используют <iframe> для видео контента_ - не могу сказать :) _А может расширения браузера имеют доступ к <iframe>_ - стоит попробовать, у расширений _обычно_ немного больше полномочий, по крайней мере по запросу

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71461/discussion-between---and-grundy).